# Android icons position

Tags: android

I want to get icon positions from active screen on Android, i mean main screen, not menu.
Does anybody know how detect size and position of icon in Android, is it possible?
I can't find any manual about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get icon positions from active screen on Android, i mean main screen, not menu.

There is no concept of "main screen" in Android.

> Does anybody know how detect size and position of icon in Android, is it possible?

If the "icon" is in your activity, find the `ImageView` or other widget that is showing the icon, and you can find out its position.

If the "icon" is anywhere else, you cannot find out what icons exist, let alone their position, in third-party apps or the OS.

Comment: Why? I think it's something like layer with icons over the main screen. And system know about icons on screen. So i think i'm should have some method to find the positions where is the icon placed (coordinates).

Comment: @Pepelac: "Why?" -- because those are other apps running in other processes. You have no rights to spy on the actions of other apps running in other processes. "So i think i'm should have some method to find the positions where is the icon placed (coordinates)." -- you are welcome to download the Android source code, modify it to have the holes you seek, build that into your own ROM mod, and install that on whatever devices you can.